# android studio app folder missing

Tags: android-studio

I have created a new project in android studio and the app folder is missing. I need to resolve dependencies in `build.gradle` which is located inside the app folder.

[image: Project Explorer pic]

Answer (score 0):

You have selected multiple form factors for your app like below.

[image: screenshot 1]

That's why it's showing `mobile` and `wear` folders instead of `app`. So, now just double click on `mobile` folder you will get app level `build.gradle` file. Same thing for the `wear` folder.

[image: screenshot 2]

If you want only mobile app development then you don't have to select `wear` form factor while creating the project. Then you only get `app` folder in your project.