# App folder missing Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This may sound familiar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218124/android-studio-app-folder-missing) but my case is little bit different.

In my case app folder is missing.

**What i have tried:**

Updated the gradle version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` and i am also using Android studio 3.0.1 current stable release available for MAC.

**Problem**

In Project Structure it is missing **app** directory. Which is commonly present in every project. I am just curious why this structure is different than others

**Info**

I got this project from a colleague, So i don't know how this is created(steps taken).

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: try to change project structure from **project** to **android**

Comment: You can create any kind of structure while creating new project, so maybe ask your colleague and he will clarify.

Comment: Rahul follow the @Nilesh Rathod Answer

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks for your response. I did but it is showing the main folder of the project in which app folder is suppose to present.

Comment: @RahulKhurana check below ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740772/7666442 of #VladMatvienko

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my Android studio and i managed to fix by **Syncing My Project with gradle files**.
Go to **File Menu** and just click on **Sync Project with Gradle files** solved my problem.
Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem. It should work just fine.
The project might be created in older version of Android Studio/Eclipse, where it didn't use `gradle` structure. It was common structure before `gradle`

Comment: so, is this will make any kind of difference while uploading app to PlayStore? Because PlayStore team will go through the code to make it approve.

Comment: @RahulKhurana, no any difference.